# How to parse a markdown string to html code

Tags: angular

I'm trying to parse a string which contains some Markdown code (like bold or italic), and I want it to be parsed and shown as HTML code.

I created a pipe which detects some Markdown tags (bold and italic only at the moment), so it car convert it into html tags like this:

```html
<span>{{ line | markdown }}</span>
```

Imagine the following string `this is *italic* and this is **bold**`.

The parsing is working, so it returns this line:
`this is <em>italic</em> and this is <strong>bold</strong>`.
The problem is the page doesn't interpret the String as html code, but a plain text.

---

So I tried to ad [innerHTML] tag like this:

```html
<span [innerHTML]=line>{{ line | markdown }}</span>
```

Now, the page shows this :
this is *italic* and this is **bold**

---

Why does it parse the bold but ignores italic, and how can I get what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it should be `<span [innerHtml]="line | markdown"></span>`. it this case output of a pipe will be passed as innerHtml to a span

Answer (score 0):

As has already been mentioned the syntax was not quite correct for having the return of the pipe be the actual inner HTML.

I would also recommend using a library for markdown to HTML conversion rather than try and do this yourself. Save yourself the time :)

All you need to do is pass the argument of the pipe to the library entry point and return the HTML.